# k8s listen to custom resource changes

Tags: go

In my operator I need to call to other **custom resource** (which is not related to my operator) and listen to to changes in it (when you apply the file again)
Im trying to use “unstructured” ,  but this line `cr1 := e.ObjectNew.(NewRuntimeClass)` not working  , I want to read the value of
The custom resource , what am I missing here ?

```
func myPredicate(name string) predicate.Predicate {
    return predicate.Funcs{
        UpdateFunc: func(e event.UpdateEvent) bool {
            cr1 := e.ObjectNew.(NewRuntimeClass)
            if cr1.Name == name {
                return true
            }
            return false
        },
    }
}func NewRuntimeClass(name string) *unstructured.Unstructured {
    return &unstructured.Unstructured{
        Object: map[string]interface{}{
            "kind":       "foo",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": map[string]interface{}{
                "name": name,
            },
        },
    }
}
```

This is the predicate api
https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/references/event-filtering/

For example this works for **config map** (when user update the CM the event is called) , the only change that I need that I need to "listen" to custom resource and not `ConfigMap`

```
func specificConfigMap(name, namespace string) predicate.Predicate {
    return predicate.Funcs{
        UpdateFunc: func(e event.UpdateEvent) bool {
            configmap := e.ObjectNew.(*corev1.ConfigMap)
            if configmap.Name == “myconfigmap” && configmap.Namespace == “mynamespace” {
                return true
            }
            return false
        },
    }
}

func (r *GuestbookReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&webappv1.Guestbook{}).
        Owns(&corev1.ConfigMap{}). ownership over the configmap
        WithEventFilter(specificConfigMap("cm1","myns")).
        Complete(r)
}
```